# Postman - 400 Bad Request

Tags: api, postman, http-status-code-400

I am trying to hit API on Postman. The API is working on server but I am not receiving any data. Here are the visual images:

[image]

It is responding me with "No Data" and 400 Bad Request.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it's this API: https://market.mashape.com/navii/daily-fuel-price-india#main-version

[image: Postman]

Add the `Content-Type: application/json` header instead of the one you have.

[image: Postman_Header]

And the body would be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Danny.. Your answer helped, I was putting body under "form-data" instead "raw". Got the response.

Comment: But how you will do it for the attachment like excel upload?

Comment: Create a new question and explain the problem. It's much easier than piggybacking onto one that looks the same. 

Answer (score 2):

There is only one thing you are missing.

- Just put the body under **raw** instead of **form-data**

It will work.

Answer (score 1):

It's paid APIand I don't want to pay for it, so let me guess ;)

1. Shouldn't you set 'Content-Type: application/json' ?
2. Do you provide body in this request - I guess you should set something like this:

   `{"fuel":"p","state":"dl"}`

Comment: I had already paid for it. I tried both of these points. Though, thank you for answering. It can help @Michali